# Reading POM version from pom.xml in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to read data from pom.xml and display its value in any of the Angular component.

For example - I need to access/get version in pom.xml and display that value in Angular component.
below is part from pom.xml

```
<groupId>appName</groupId>
<artifactId>credit</artifactId>
<version>1.0.13.0-dev</version>  <!-- THIS FIELD i want in angular-->
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Also i need to ensure that after deployment i am able to get the latest updated version also..

Comment: load it using `XHR` and use the [responseXML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseXML) to read through it? Otherwise you can use `fetch` and just run a regex capture.

Comment: Okay can you please specify it with example

Answer (score 1):

1. if your angular app is inside your java app (spring boot for example)

you can make use of the frontend-maven-plugin to create an environmentVariable which can be used by your webpack build

```
<plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>webpack build dev</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>run webpack:build</arguments>
                                    <environmentVariables>
                                        <APP_VERSION>${project.version}</APP_VERSION>
                                    </environmentVariables>                                  
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

inside your webpack plugin:
if you dont know how to use custom webpack for angular app you can look at this
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack

```
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                // APP_VERSION is passed as an environment variable from the Maven build tasks.
                VERSION: `'${process.env.hasOwnProperty('APP_VERSION') ? process.env.APP_VERSION : 'DEFAULT'}'`
            }
        }),
```

then in your .ts file (a file containing constants for example)

```
export const VERSION = process.env.VERSION;
```

1.2 another solution is to parse directly the pom.xml using a js (ts) script and read the version tag inside the pom.xml

2. if your angular app is not inside your java app, you need to expose the version through a rest api

Comment: ya currently my application is not inside spring boot, its just having its own pom.xml. I need to look for parsing directly pom.xml file... @gaetanTEMATE

Comment: if i understand your angular app is a different maven module, can your give the structure of your project

Comment: i tried using node version.js @gaetanTEMATE it worked locally :) but not on Jenkins deployment. Please have a look at my below question which i raised just now  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63324756/execute-angular-npm-script-through-maven

Comment: how is your project structure? where is your angular app according to your java app?